# yticklabel pos=right has no effect

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, labels, ticks

I am using `pgfplots` to draw a simple 2D function. I'd like to display all of the ytick labels on the right side of the plot. So far I had no success using `yticklabel pos=right`, I do not get an error but the label is just rendered on the left. Is it possible at all?

Here is my code (with a few shortenings):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ticks=none,
            ymajorticks=true,
            xmajorticks=true,
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            enlargelimits = true,
            ymin=0, xmin=0,
            xlabel={Zeit},
            ylabel={kum. fakturierbarer Wert},
            title style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north,align=center},
            title={{\textsf{\textbf{\textsc{Mit Teilmengen}}}}},
            xtick={0,3,6},
            xticklabels={Startdatum,heute,Enddatum},
            xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north east,xshift=5mm},
            ylabel style={at={(current axis.left of origin)},xshift=15mm},
            x tick label style={anchor=north},
            extra x ticks={0,3,6},
            extra x tick labels={},
            extra x tick style={grid=major},
            ytick={6},
            yticklabels={Planwert},
            yticklabel pos=right,
            extra y ticks={6},
            extra y tick labels={},
            extra y tick style={grid=major}]
        \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] coordinates {
                     (0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 1) (2, 1) (2, 2) (3, 2) 
                     (3, 3) (4, 3) (4, 4) (5, 4) (5, 5) (6, 5)
                     (6, 6) (7, 6) (8, 6)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Here's a picture of what I have:
[image]

And here is the picture of what I want to have:
[image]

Comment: Please give a full (compilable) but minimal code of your graph. Like this, it is very hard to try fixes for you. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it, have already posted the complete code.

Comment: @ax1mx2 Please include the whole (but in the most minimal form possible) document, including `\documentclass` and any `usepackages` so that people can simply copy-paste-compile your code to try fixes. Thanks!

Comment: @ax1mx2 Please note the changes I've made in your code to make it compilable, and please try to construct similar examples in the future! Thanks :-) PS Good question!

Comment: @darthbith I'll take note, Thank you for the suggestion! I just did not wish to overblow the code too much, but two lines more or less don't seem to hurt.

Comment: The documentation says that this option is only relevant for boxed axes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, as a matter of fact, I managed to find another solution through trial and error.

I wrapped the `tikzpicture` in a `minipage` and I used this trick to position the text relative to the right end of the `minipage` with the following `y tick label style={at={(current axis.east)},anchor=west,xshift=\textwidth}`. Its probably a little bit less hacking and this seems to work better for me, so I thought sharing would be nice, though it might not be the best solution.

And here is the whole code (at compilable state):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=11pt]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\newcommand{\lblfont}[1]{\fontsize{8.5}{4}\selectfont \emph{#1}}


\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htb]
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}   %%% The function plot occupies half of the page
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ticks=none,
            ymajorticks=true,
            xmajorticks=true,
            axis x line=bottom,
            axis y line=left,
            enlargelimits = true,
            ymin=0, xmin=0,
            xlabel={Zeit},
            ylabel={kum. fakturierbarer Wert},
            title style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north,align=center},
            title={{\textsf{\textbf{\textsc{Mit Teilmengen}}}}},
            xtick={0,3,6},
            xticklabels={\lblfont{Startdatum},\lblfont{heute},\lblfont{Enddatum}},
            xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north east},
            x tick label style={anchor=north},
            y tick label style={at={(current axis.east)},anchor=west,xshift=\textwidth},  %%% <---- Little trick
            extra x ticks={0,3,6},
            extra x tick labels={},
            extra x tick style={grid=major},
            ytick={6},
            yticklabels={\lblfont{Planwert}},
            extra y ticks={6},
            extra y tick labels={},
            extra y tick style={grid=major}]
        \addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] coordinates {
                     (0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 1) (2, 1) (2, 2) (3, 2) 
                     (3, 3) (4, 3) (4, 4) (5, 4) (5, 5) (6, 5)
                     (6, 6) (7, 6) (8, 6)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And here is the visual result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is some work around.

Add `clip=false` and then add a node at the end of plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\def\lblfont{\itshape}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
clip=false,
width=.97\textwidth,
ticks=none,
ymajorticks=true,
xmajorticks=true,
axis x line=bottom,
axis y line=left,
enlargelimits = true,
ymin=0, xmin=0,
xlabel={Zeit},
ylabel={kum. fakturierbarer Wert},
title style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},anchor=north,align=center},
title={{\textsf{\textbf{\textsc{Mit Teilmengen}}}}},
xtick={0,3,6},
xticklabels={\lblfont{Startdatum},\lblfont{heute},\lblfont{Enddatum}},
xlabel style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=north,yshift=-10mm},
ylabel style={at={(current axis.left of origin)},xshift=15mm},
x tick label style={anchor=north},
extra x ticks={0,3,6},
extra x tick labels={},
extra x tick style={grid=major},
ytick=\empty,
extra y ticks={6},
extra y tick labels={},
extra y tick style={grid=major}
]
\addplot [mark=*,mark size=0.7] coordinates {
               (0, 0) (1, 0) (1, 1) (2, 1) (2, 2) (3, 2)
               (3, 3) (4, 3) (4, 4) (5, 4) (5, 5) (6, 5)
               (6, 6) (7, 6) (8, 6)}node[pos=1.11]{\lblfont{Planwert}};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason  yticklabel pos=upper  ???

This is from the pgfplots_1.18.1 documentation:

"The second change is rather simple: we only added the option yticklabel pos=upper to the second axis. This moves all tick labels to the right, without changing anything else."